# How to make nested query with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
schedule_association_table = Table(
    'schedule_association', Base.metadata,
    Column('course_id', Integer, ForeignKey('course.idx')),
    Column('schedule_id', Integer, ForeignKey('schedule.idx')),
)
class Schedule(Base):
    __tablename__ = "schedule"
    idx = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    start_time = Column(Time())
    end_time = Column(Time())

class Course(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'course'
    idx = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    course_id = Column(String(16))
    schedules = relationship("Schedule", backref="courses", secondary=schedule_association_table)
```

In this model, I want to query course that between start_time and end_time.  I can query by below way, but It is not good solution. Any other better way in here?

```
def get_course_between_time(start_time, end_time):
    result = []
    for course in db.session(Course).all():
        for schedule in course.schedules:
            if start_time < schedule.start_time and end_time > schedule.end_time:
                result.append(course)
                break
    return result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could [use EXISTS](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html#using-exists) to query Courses that have a related Schedule that meets the criteria:

```
def get_course_between_time(start_time, end_time):
    courses = db.session.query(Course).\
        filter(Course.schedules.any((Schedule.start_time > start_time) &
                                    (Schedule.end_time < end_time))).\
        all()

    return courses
```